# java swing jScrollpane remove excess space

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

i'm working with JScrollPane today and this is what i've managed to do so far

```
package it.polimi.ingsw.ps11.view.graphicView;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestIt2 extends JPanel {
   private static final Dimension BUTTON_SIZE = new Dimension(170, 150);
   private Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   private JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

   public TestIt2() {
       buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
      JPanel holderPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      holderPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      holderPanel.add(Box.createGlue(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(new JScrollPane(holderPanel,
              JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
              JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      createButton();
   }

   public class addButton implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        createButton();     
    }
   }

   protected void createButton() {
      JButton button = new JButton("click me");
      button.addActionListener(new addButton());
      button.setPreferredSize(BUTTON_SIZE);
      buttonPanel.add(button);
      revalidate();
      repaint();
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(screen.width / 10 * 2,
            screen.height / 10 * 2);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TestIt2 mainPanel = new TestIt2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestIt2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}`
```

The problem is that the scrollpane adds a lot of space on the right of the buttons i created even tho there's still space. 
How can I modify my code so it doesn't hava all that free space, but instead my last button is right on the border of the scrollPane,, and every new button take just the space it needs? Thank all you guys

Comment: `button.setMaximumSize(BUTTON_SIZE);`

Comment: Use a `FlowLayout` instead of a BoxLayout. A FlowLayout will respect the preferred size of a component. The BoxLayout will respect the maximum size, so having the different preferred/maximum size is causing a weird layout.